# If $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function and $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ must $f(z) = z $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an entire function and $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $ must $f(z) = z $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I can't apply the Identity Theorem here as the set  $ { n \in \mathbb{N} } $ doesn't have any limit points.

Comment: $z+\sin \pi z$ works too (if we know something about the order of $f$ eg like it is less than $1$ than the answer is yes for somewhat more sophisticated reasons)

Comment: I see, so the statement is not true. Thank you :)

Comment: in general, the statement is not true; however, if you have some extra conditions that limit the growth of $f$, it becomes true; there is lot of theory about this

Answer (score 0):

The [Weierstrass Product Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassProductTheorem.html) (see e.g. Theorem IV.2.1 of [Complex Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-30823-7) by Eberhard Freitag and Rolf Busam) says that if you have a discrete subset $S$ of $\Bbb C$ and a prescription of the order of poles $m: S \to \Bbb Z_{>0}$, then there is an entire function $f$ that vanishes exactly on $S$, such that the order of the zero at each $s \in S$ is exactly $m(s)$.

So for the case $S = \Bbb Z$ you can get $f(z) = \sin(\pi z)$, which witnesses the failure of your claim.

---

On the other hand if $S$ is not discrete (and non-empty) then it follows from the identity theorem.